# How to remove flutter_facebook_auth packages from flutter app?

Tags: flutter, fbsdk

I would like to remove the following sub-dependency packages from my flutter app, that are listed in my pubspec.lock file (not pubspec.yaml):

flutter_facebook_auth
flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface
flutter_facebook_auth_web

My app does not use Facebook auth.  It is not enabled as one of the sign-in providers in the Firebase console.  It is also not listed as a provider:

`FlutterFireUIAuth.configureProviders([ const EmailProviderConfiguration(), const GoogleProviderConfiguration(clientId: googleClientId), const AppleProviderConfiguration(), ]);`

I understand they may be installed by default as part of the firebase_auth package.  Is there any way to remove them?

When running the app, I had previously received warnings related to FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled and FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled, and I have set both to false in the Info.plist file. Unfortunately, I still get those 3 facebook packages when running pod install or pod update.

I have already tried running `flutter clean` as well as deleting the podfile.lock file in the ios folder.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth) it says you need to install facebook plugin separately.

try

```
$ flutter pub cache repair

$ flutter clean

$ flutter pub get
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this and it still gets downloaded. I'm quite sure it was not installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to remove the packages from the project:

**Step 1:** Navigate to `pubspec.yaml` in your project root directory.

**Step 2:** Remove the package name that you want to remove from the project.

*This section typically looks like this:*

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  package_name_to_remove: ^x.y.z
  ...
```

**Step 3:** Now run the following command:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

*It applied on the Android project (by default)*

*For iOS build (need additional work):*

- Ensure that you have set the `FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled` and `FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled` to **false** in your *Info.plist* file. It's important to disable these settings to avoid Facebook-related warnings.
- Delete Pods: Delete the `Pods` folder and the `Podfile.lock` file in the ios directory of your Flutter project.
- Reinstall Pods: Run pod install in the iOS directory of your Flutter project to update the iOS dependencies:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: I think he needs to remove a sub dependency, not the one in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Yes, it is a sub dependency.  Sorry for the confusion, I added this information to the top now.  The package is not listed in pubspec.yaml.  It's listed in pubspec.lock only.

Comment: @yizaho What I understood from your comment, you already removed the main package but sub-packages are still listed in the `pubspec.lock` & you want to remove it. Am I correct?

Comment: These sub dependencies are not listed in pubspec.yaml (i did not remove them).  they only show up in pubspec.lock

Answer (score 0):

There is a Flutter command to remove packages:

```
dart pub remove <package1> [<package2>...]
```

or

```
flutter pub remove <package1> [<package2>...]
```

You must be in the directory where your `pubspec.yaml` is.

Comment: does this work for sub-dependencies?  i couldn't get that to work

Comment: I should. Read the help for the command: `dart pub remove --help`